# Can't import modules with Typescript

Tags: typescript, razor, visual-studio-2017

I'm having a really hard time trying to import the module A:

```
export module A {
    export class A_Class {
    }
}
```

into my module B:

```
import { A } from "./a";

let a = new A.A_Class();
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "files": [
    "a.ts",
    "b.ts",
  ]
}
```

My `cshtml` has this script section:

```
<script type="module" src="~/Scripts/app/b.js"></script>
```

And the chrome browser gives me the error:

```
http://localhost:64518/Scripts/app/a net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

For `line 1` on `b.js`:

```
import { A } from "./a";
```

I'm completely out of ideas and have tried many combinations of `es6`, `commonjs`, etc, with the errors on `import` varying just a little bit.

I'm using `Typescript 3.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
import { A } from "./a";
```

To this:

```
import { A } from "./a.js";
```

The file "a" doesn't actually exist, so Chrome is unable to find it. `a.js` though, should exist.

If you're running this behind a server or if you're using a module loader like SystemJS, you might be able to have requests without a file extension add `.js` to the request if a file isn't found, otherwise you'll need to put in the extension manually in your imports.